# INFORMATION_SCHEMA Query Is Running Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

Please go easy on me as this is my first post.

I'm having trouble figuring out what will fix the following query on our INFORMATION_SCHEMA from running so slow. To my knowledge, these views are locked down pretty well. This is on SQL Server 2014 Standard.

Recently, we restored the database on which this query was used. This database is the test version of a production database. Before that restore, this query ran in a few seconds or fewer, but now it takes 3-5+ minutes to return 36 rows. This query runs significantly quicker with the final line commented out, to the tune of 4 seconds or so, returning 60 rows.

Does anyone have any ideas of what to do to make this fast again?

Additional details that may answer a few more questions: the query takes this long on the production database as well. There aren't any indexes on the views.

```
    SELECT pf.TABLE_CATALOG AS PK_TABLE_DATABASE, 
           pf.TABLE_SCHEMA AS PK_SCHEMA_NAME, 
           pf.TABLE_NAME AS PK_TABLE_NAME,
           pf.COLUMN_NAME AS PK_FIELD_NAME, 
           ff.TABLE_CATALOG AS FK_TABLE_DATABASE, 
           ff.TABLE_SCHEMA AS FK_SCHEMA_NAME,
           ff.TABLE_NAME AS FK_TABLE_NAME, 
           ff.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_FIELD_NAME, 
           pf.ORDINAL_POSITION AS ORDINAL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ff
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ff.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ff.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = ff.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE pf 
    ON rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pf.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pf.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = pf.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND ff.ORDINAL_POSITION = pf.ORDINAL_POSITION --line in question
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I must be missing something - why join `JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` twice?  I don't see anything differentiating them.

Comment: To get the table and field information for both the PK and FK in the combination.

Answer (score 1):

I would try things in this order:
1) Update statistics 
2) Rebuild indexes
3) Verify the memory available in the machine is not under pressure. 
4) check for some type of activity or locks (sp_lock)

Comment: Wouldn't I need an index on those views to be able to update statistics on them? I'm not able to see where that information comes from in that view also.

Comment: I needed the "nolock" clue here - I was stuck behind a job running a linked server import.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT pf.TABLE_CATALOG AS PK_TABLE_DATABASE, 
           pf.TABLE_SCHEMA AS PK_SCHEMA_NAME, 
           pf.TABLE_NAME AS PK_TABLE_NAME,
           pf.COLUMN_NAME AS PK_FIELD_NAME, 
           ff.TABLE_CATALOG AS FK_TABLE_DATABASE, 
           ff.TABLE_SCHEMA AS FK_SCHEMA_NAME,
           ff.TABLE_NAME AS FK_TABLE_NAME, 
           ff.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_FIELD_NAME, 
           pf.ORDINAL_POSITION AS ORDINAL
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ff
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE pf 
ON ff.ORDINAL_POSITION = pf.ORDINAL_POSITION --line in question 
where exists
(
select 1 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
where rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ff.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ff.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = ff.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    and rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pf.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pf.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = pf.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
)
```

Comment: Hey KumarHarsh, that query still takes a while as well. Around the same as the original query.